# MySQL изменение даты в формате `text`

Tags: mysql

Есть поле формата `text` содержащее дату, пример даты: `02.05.2015`.
Возникла необходимость переписать год в полях БД (на один год больше: `XX.XX.2016`).
Возможно ли данную запись изменить посредством mySQL не прибегая к стороннему коду?

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html Смотрите функцию replace

Comment: Лучше теми же строковыми функциями преобразовать к формату, который может быть корректно распознан как литерал даты, затем функциями даты-времени прибавить год, после чего выполнить обратное преобразование в нужный формат. Ну хотя бы для того, чтобы не получить 29 февраля в невисокосном году...